# How does Spark decides no of Jobs?

Tags: apache-spark

As I understander spark decides no of jobs based on each Action performed. I have 6 actions in my spark which are further divided into stages but i see more than 6 jobs are being spawned.

Is my understanding correct or i am missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: If the output of the transformation is something other than another dataframe or rdd, then an action is being performed. Are you sure that you only have 6 actions ?

Comment: I guess this is hapening because of for which i have in code... Looping is causing more than 6 stages to spawn.. I fixed this problem.